# SAS proc compare unequal value

Tags: sas, compare

I want to automate some process. 
I used SAS proc compare and I can get variables list with unequal values.
Further I want to extract these variables (with unequal values) and compare their means/median/min/max etc. using either proc means or proc uni-variate. 
My question is how can I save the proc compare output as a table and extract variables from there? Thank you.

Comment: Show your `COMPARE` code.  Are there `BY` groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about saving the output of Proc compare in another dataset/table, then you can use out option:

```
proc compare base=old compare=new
out=Out_ds outnoequal outbase outcomp outdif noprint;
id code;
run;
```

the out_ds will keep the results.

Refer below to keep only the different variable names in output Dataset:

```
data old;
input code A B C D;
datalines;
101 1 a 1 100
102 2 b 1 104
103 3 c 1 54
104 4 d 1 87
105 5 e 1 201
;
run;

data new;
input code A B C D;
datalines;
101 1 a 1 100
102 2 b 1 13
103 3 c 1 54
104 4 d 2 87
105 5 e 1 12
;
run;

proc sort data=old; by code; run;
proc sort data=new; by code; run;

/*suppresses the writing of an observation to the output data set when all values in the observation are judged equal. 
  In addition, in observations containing values for some variables judged equal and others judged unequal, 
  the OUTNOEQUAL option uses the special missing value ".E" to represent differences and percent differences for variables judged equal.*/
proc compare base=old compare=new
out=Out_ds outnoequal;
id code;
run;

/*Get all the variable names from output dataset which you are comparing*/
proc sql ;
  select strip(name)
    into :vnames
    separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns
   where libname="WORK" and
         upcase(memname)="OUT_DS" and
         upcase(strip(name)) not in('_TYPE_','_OBS_','CODE')
  ;
quit;

/*This macro will loop through every value and will keep only those variables in keep_vars, which have unequal values*/
options merror mprint nosymbolgen mlogic;
%macro keepv(varlist);
data out_ds1;
length keep_vars $100.;
     set out_ds;
     retain keep_vars;
     %let var_c=%sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
     %do i=1 %to &var_c;
     %let var_t=%sysfunc(scan(&varlist,&i));
        if strip(&var_t) ne 'E' and findc(keep_vars,"&var_t") ne 1 then 
        do;
            keep_vars=catx(",",keep_vars,"&var_t");
        end;
     %end;
    run;
%mend keepv;

%keepv(&vnames);

/*keep the last obs -  keep_vars have the required variable names only*/
data out_ds_final;
if 0 then set out_ds1 nobs=nobs end=eof;
set out_ds1 point=nobs;
output;
stop;
keep keep_vars;
run;

proc print data=out_ds_final; run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `OUTSTATS=` option will output basic statistics for the variables.  The stats are `N, MEAN, STD, MIN, MAX, STDERR, T, PROBT, NDIF, DIFMEANS, and R,RSQ`

If you need to compute statistics other than those, you can further process the OUTSTATS table to create a list of variables that had some differences (per `NDIF`).

Example:

```
data have1 have2;
  do row = 1 to 100;
    array x(100);

    do _n_ = 1 to dim (x);
      x(_n_) = _n_ * 1000 + floor(50*ranuni(123)) - 25;
    end;
    output have1;

    * every 5th row in every 5th column have2 could be different;
    if mod(row,5) = 0 then
      do _n_ = 1 to dim (x);
        if mod(_n_,5) = 0 and ranuni(123) < _n_ / 100 then x(_n_) + _n_;
      end;
    output have2;
  end;
run;

proc compare noprint 
  base=have1 
  compare=have2 
  out=differences
  outstats=summary_stats
  outnoequal
  ;
run;
* review summary_stats;

* need more stats than in summary_stats ?
* get list of variables have some differences;
proc sql;
  reset noprint;
  select _var_
  into :vars_that_differed separated by ' '
  from summary_stats
  where _TYPE_ = 'NDIF' and (_BASE_ ne 0 or _COMP_ ne 0)
  ;
quit;

* show the variables that would used in VAR statement of subsequent MEANS or UNIVARIATE;
%put NOTE: &=vars_that_differed;
----- LOG -----
NOTE: VARS_THAT_DIFFERED=x5 x10 x20 x25 x30 x35 x40 x45 x50 x55 x60 x65 x70
x75 x80 x85 x90 x95 x100
```

Comment: The second answer is more close to what I asked. I just want to output the unequal variable names , not the actually obs. For example, there are 4 attributes A B C D in two data sets. the ABC values can have exact math, but there are 5 obs for D don't match. I want to output the name of variable D instead of the 5 obs.

Comment: Thank you, you code generate the output I want. Thank you for putting all the commends in the code. They are very helpful for learning the SAS grammar. I vote the second one because it is more concise and it output a macro so I can call it directly in my other program.